# Pandas Frequency Conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find if is possible to use `data.asfreq(MonthEnd())` with no `date_range` created data.
What I'm trying to achive. I run csv query with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/FRED/GDPC1.csv?api_key=", parse_dates=True)
data.columns = ["period", "integ"]
data['period'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['period'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Then I want to assign frequency to my 'period' column by doing this:

```
tdelta = data.period[1] - data.period[0]
data.period.freq = tdelta
```

And some print comands:

```
print(data)
print(data.period.freq)
print(data.dtypes)
```

Returns:

```
..........
270 1948-07-01   2033.2
271 1948-04-01   2021.9
272 1948-01-01   1989.5
273 1947-10-01   1960.7
274 1947-07-01   1930.3
275 1947-04-01   1932.3
276 1947-01-01   1934.5

[277 rows x 2 columns]
-92 days +00:00:00
period    datetime64[ns]
integ            float64
dtype: object
```

I can also parse the original 'DATE' column by making it 'index':

```
data = pd.read_csv("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/FRED/GDPC1.csv?api_key=", parse_dates=True, index_col='DATE')
```

What I want to do is just to covert the quarterly data in to monthly rows. For example:

```
270 1948-07-01   2033.2
271 1948-06-01   NaN
272 1948-05-01   NaN
273 1948-04-01   2021.9
274 1948-03-01   NaN
275 1948-02-01   NaN
276 1948-01-01   1989.5
......and so on.......
```

I'm eventually trying to do this by using `ts.asfreq(MonthBegin())` and , `ts.asfreq(MonthBegin(), method='pad')`. So far unsuccessfully. I have the following error:

```
NameError: name 'MonthBegin' is not defined
```

My question is can I use `asfreq` if I don't use `date_range` to create the frame? Somehow to 'pass' my date column to the function. If this is not the solution is it there any other easy way to convert quarterly to monthly frequency?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear on what the problem is... Try `ts.asfreq('M', how='start', method='pad')`.

Comment: I should be looking better in the documentation. I try it but it don't change the series in any way. It don't poduce any error as well. I tryed to change 'M' with 'W' to see if something. Not at all. However when I change it to 'MS' it says `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TimeGrouper`:

```
import pandas as pd

periods = ['1948-07-01', '1948-04-01', '1948-01-01', '1947-10-01',
           '1947-07-01', '1947-04-01', '1947-01-01']
integs = [2033.2, 2021.9, 1989.5, 1960.7, 1930.3, 1932.3, 1934.5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'period': pd.to_datetime(periods), 'integ': integs})
df = df.set_index('period')

df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('MS')).sum().sort_index(ascending=False)
```

EDIT: You can also use `resample` instead of a `TimeGrouper`:

```
df.resample('MS').sum().sort_index(ascending=False)
```

Comment: Is it any way I can pass my columns to the function. For example `periods=data.period` and `integs = data.integ`. The problem is they are hundreds of rows.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, import your data with `data = pd.read_csv(“…”, parse_dates=True, index_col='DATE’)` (as you do above) and then do
`data.resample('MS').sum().sort_index(ascending=False)`.

Comment: Same notting change. No error as well. The code now looks very simple `import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/FRED/GDPC1.csv?api_key=", parse_dates=True, index_col='DATE')` Then the new function `data.resample('MS').sum().sort_index(ascending=False)`. This is the result from `print(data.dtypes)` - `VALUE    float64
dtype: object`. There is no any proper date type. Is it possible to do `resample` if don't have the actual frequency?

Comment: The dates are in the index. You can reset them as a column by appending `.reset_index()` to the resample command.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you right. I added `data.reset_index()`   before `data.resample('MS').sum().sort_index(ascending=False)`. I'm not sure this is what I have to do but there is still no change and no error.

Comment: `data = data.resample('MS').sum().sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index()`

Comment: This one works perfect. Thanks a lot. Just a final thing - how I can fill the missing rows. `method='pad'` is not part of `resample` and I didn't find similar argument there.

Comment: Actualy there is `fill_method` but `fill_method='pad'` do not return it properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115890/discussion-between-al-ivon-and-alberto-garcia-raboso).